# dblink not reflecting updates on table of one table to another while in a process

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

i have 2 databases in a server. while running archival process changes done on one table are not recognized by other table in 2nd db

i am using dblink to connect the databases

commit not working

the inserting of rows of a table named table_nm form xy to xx;

```
sql_str := 'select dblink_exec(''host=xx user=xx password=x x dbname=xy'',''insert into '||table_nm||' (select * from dblink(''''host=xx user=xx password=x dbnaxme=xx'''',''''select * from '||table_nm||'  '||condition ||''''') as t12('||v_data_type||'))'')';

execute sql_str;
```

deleting those records from xy

```
sql_str:='DELETE FROM '||table_nm||' '||condition||' ';
   execute sql_str;
```

in the nest loop the items that are deleted from xy are also inserted leading to duplicate records in xx

Comment: Could you create simple example that demonstrates this problem? Preferably one that can be used to reproduce this behavior by other people.

Comment: i have given the sample queries